# Access JavaScript global Variable from Swift and change its value using JSContext

Tags: javascript, swift, wkwebview

I'm using WKWebView Scrip Message Handler to run functionality from JS in my Swift project.
However, I need to return JSON value in some of the functions I'm calling.
What I've done was to check a Global variable in my HTML using JS and now i need to set the value.

I accomplished that by using EvaluateJavaScript but it's not good to me because the value cannot be changes while I'm in the process of other JS Function.

Im looking for a way to access the global variable and change its value using JSContext - Is it possible.
I'm open for other options as well.

This is the code I'm using now to set the variable:

```
  mainWebView?.evaluateJavaScript(stringToEvaluate, completionHandler: { (objevt: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) in
            if ((error) == nil){
                print("Error: %@",error?.description);
            }
            else{

                self.mainWebView?.evaluateJavaScript("console.log(\"JSON Returned Sucsessfully\");", completionHandler:nil)
                context.evaluateScript("console.log(\"JSON Returned Sucsessfully\");");
            }
        })
```